# How to create an inverted $S$ cruve

Tags: curves

I'm looking for a way to create an inverted $S$ curve function. Below is an image of what I want. Left is a regular S curve, on the right is the kind of curve I want. [Here](https://www.image-line.com/fl-studio-learning/fl-studio-online-manual/html/automation_form.htm) are the allowed set of operations that I can use:

[image]

Comment: How about $x^3$?

Comment: With these vertical tangents and flat middle I would go for $x(a-\sqrt{1-x^2})$. With $a=1$ flat, with $a>1$ some slope.

Comment: Can you specify the domain and range? There are plenty of inverse sigmoid functions to pick from, but they all have vertical asymptotes, i.e. shoot up to infinifty. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a function which does what I wanted to do:

$$
f(x)=-\frac{(1-2x)^3}{2}+0.5
$$

[Image of the curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LPbv.png)

Answer (score 2):

Possible with *Inverse function* where  function inversion is possible. The given graph indicates an odd function, straight forward function inversion solution. In polar coordinates $ r(\theta) = r(-\theta).$

In other cases absolute values to be taken and later on modified suitably.

$$ y= f(x)\to x= f(y) $$

$$ or$$

$$ y= f(x)\to y_{inv}= f^{-1}(x_{inv}) $$

[image]

In the above we have inverse tanh brown  function solution graphed along with starting green tanh function. Similarly the sine function.

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, I wanted a range for x of [0, 1] with the y value being nondecreasing from 0 to 1 in this range. I found a function which does this, I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Using complex variables, we can transform the exact $S$-curve you started with very easily. Let us assume the inflection point passes through the origin and let the curve be expressed parametrically as $z(t)$. The first thing we want to do is to flip the curve about the $x$-axis, then rotate it $90^{\circ}$ counterclockwise, the the desired curve becomes

$$w(t)=z^*(t)e^{i\pi/2}=iz^*(t)$$

In Cartesian coordinates then

$$w(t)=i\big(x(t)-iy(t)\big)=y(t)+ix(t)$$

Which means that all you have to do is to switch $x$ and $y$. You can see as much by just flipping your original image about.